# Libtorch: How to make a Tensor with GPU pointer?

Tags: gpu, libtorch

Below is the pseudo-code of what I want to do.
I already know how to move tensor to GPU (`.cuda()`)... 
But have no idea about using a GPU pointer to make a new tensor.
Is there any method I've missed? 
I don't want to copy `devPtr` back to the host side but just make the GPU tensor with the pointer.

```
int main(void) {
  float* devPtr;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtr, sizeof(float)*HOSTDATA_SIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(devPtr, hostData, sizeof(float)*HOSTDATA_SIZE, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  torch::Tensor inA = /* make Tensor with devPtr which is already in GPU */;
  torch::Tensor inB = torch::randn({1, 10, 512, 512}).cuda();

  torch::Tensor out = torch::matmul(inA, inB);

  std::cout << out << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work, can you confirm ?

```
auto dims = torch::IntArrayRef{1, 10, 512, 512};
auto gpu_tensor = torch::from_blob(dev_ptr, dims, torch::TensorOptions().device(torch::kCUDA))
```

Be careful, torch::from_blob does not take ownership of the pointer.If you need to make gpu_tensor independant of the lifetime of `dev_ptr`, then you need to clone it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... But.. what do you mean by doesn't take a 'ownership' ??

Comment: it means that the lifetime of the pointer `dev_ptr` will not be managed by `gpu_tensor`. If the pointer is deleted, `gpu_tensor` will still exist but using it will raise a segmentation fault (because the memory will have been deallocated). Conversely, if the tensor goes out of scope, it will not delete the pointer. So you have to be careful with the lifetime of your objects